# Sharepoint issue ListData.svc $expand maximum allowed is 7

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-web-api

I am trying the following query:

```
http://contoso/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Product()?$expand=OrderDetail/Category,Repository/Country,Repository,Origin,OrderDetail/Order&$select=Id,OrderDetail/Category/Title,Repository/Country/Title,Repository/Title,Origin/Title,OrderDetail/Category/Specification,OrderDetail/Order/ImportDate
```

I have got message:

`The request includes 8 $expand segment(s), but the maximum allowed is 7`

Is this impossible or is there another way of accomplishing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I recommend to you, instead of take your answer only with one query, Use multiple queries, that each query is responsible for fetching records of a specific list. Your query has very performance issue on Share Point.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> The request includes 8 $expand segment(s), but the maximum allowed is
>   7.

is encountered since the *maximum* number of related entities that can be included in a single request by using the `$expand` operator for [LINQ to SharePoint provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.linq.aspx) is set to `7`

**About DataServiceConfiguration**

- [DataServiceConfiguration Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration(v=vs.113).aspx) is used to manage the
  configuration data for a data service, in our case SharePoint REST service.
- [DataServiceConfiguration.MaxExpandCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration.maxexpandcount(v=vs.113).aspx) property - gets or sets the maximum number of related entities that can be included in a single request by using the $expand operator

---

One option to bypass this type of limitation would be to *extend* SharePoint REST service and increase `DataServiceConfiguration.MaxExpandCount`

### Implementation

ContosoListData.svc:

```
<%@ServiceHost language="C#" Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressDataServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Service="Contoso.SharePoint.Linq.ContosoListDataService, Contoso.SharePoint.Linq.DataService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=47134954c7026996" %>
```

ContosoListDataService.cs:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq;
using System;
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Common;

namespace Contoso.SharePoint.Linq
{
    public class ContosoListDataService : ListDataService
    {
        public new static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            if (config == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("config");
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
            config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 1000);
            config.MaxBatchCount = 1000;
            config.MaxChangesetCount = 100;
            config.MaxExpandCount = 14;  //<-- set custom 
            config.MaxExpandDepth = 7;
            config.MaxObjectCountOnInsert = 100;
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        }
    }
}
```